# PHP filling the associative array with the right key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-key

```
 $niz = array(
        'fruit1' => 'apple',
        'fruit2' => 'orange',
        'fruit3' => 'grape',
        'fruit4' => 'watermelon',
        'fruit5' => 'grapefruit'
        );

    $max = 'yellow';
    $niz2 = array();
    $niz3 = array();

    foreach($niz as $k => $v){

        if (strlen($v) <= strlen($max)) {
            array_push($niz2, $v);  
                } 
        else { 
        $niz3[$niz[$k]]=$v;
            }   
    }   
    print_r($niz3);

How can I get the appropriate key from the $niz array in my $niz3          associative array in the else statement?
```

I.e. Array( [fruit4] => watermelon
            [fruit5] => grapefruit
          )

I get:
Array ( [watermelon] => watermelon
        [grapefruit] => grapefruit 
      )

Comment: Just `$niz3[$k]=$v;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `$niz3[$niz[$k]]=$v;` to `$niz3[$k]=$v;`,

`$k` is the "key", by passiing it into `$niz` you are accessing the value, which you have already defined as `$v`.